# Is sand + water considered mud?

Tags: word-usage

Definition of *mud* according to Google:

> **mud** 
>   soft, sticky matter resulting from the mixing of earth and water.

Not sure if this applied to this:

[image]

Like, can I say that my hair became *muddy* after rolling in that stuff?

Comment: Isn't it just called *wet sand*?

Comment: It's too bad it isn't technically correct to call it 'slurry'. I like that word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image posted by the OP just tells me: **wet sand**, and  [Google images](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22wet%20sand%22&biw=1366&bih=634&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMIu4P_nL30xwIVxT8aCh1k6A3V) confirm the description.

A little investigation in Google books produced this:

> She picked up a large handful of the wet sand and threw it at him. The children delighted in this and amid peals of laughter, ... **Her hair was** dripping wet and **matted with sand**.
>
> <sub>*The Witch's Daughter: Book Two*</sub>

I would strongly suggest that the OP write something like this:

> ‘… after rolling in the wet sand, my hair was matted.’

instead of this:

> *‘My hair was muddy after rolling in the mud’*

The second version is grammatical and makes sense but the reader would have a very different image or idea from the first.

**matted**  *[especially of hair or fur) tangled into a thick mass.](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/matted)* (OD)

---

EDIT (because comments are ephemeral)

To me that image is wet sand, not mud, mud is sticky, thick goo. Wet sand when it is dried just becomes sand again. Generally speaking, a sandy beach consists of sand, a pebble beach consists of pebbles, a rocky beach ... etc. We use the expression *sandcastle*, not *mud castle*, when we talk about children filling buckets with wet sand and then turning them upside down. After a few hours in the sun, the castle dries and returns to being sand again.

Comment: If someone looks through the images, they'll see the same identical image the OP posted. To me that image is wet sand, not mud, mud is sticky, thick goo. Wet sand when it is dried just becomes sand again.

Comment: Wet sand can be sticky, thick goo too. It often contains more than just rock particles, and even if not the particles can be small enough that it is sticky and gooey. And when dried, fine sand, like dried clay mud, can become a hard crust. It's all relative to the size of the particles (and perhaps to other, "binding" chemicals). Fine enough particles in suspension gives you viscous, gooey mud.

Comment: @Drew I appreciate the finer distinction, but generally speaking,  a sandy beach consists of sand, a pebble beach consists of pebbles, a rocky beach ... etc. We use the expression *sandcastle* not *mud castle* when we talk about children filling buckets with wet sand and then turning them upside down. After a few hours in the sun, the castle dries and returns to being sand again. I know this is stating the obvious, but it seems that I have to, in order to defend my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is no, sand + water is not mud.

**Sand** is rock which has been ground down into fine particles, typically by wave action and forming beaches along the sea shore.

**Mud** is a combination of inert rock particles and organic material which has been saturated by water.

When wet sand dries out it reverts to being dry, crumbly particles.
When mud dries out completely it cracks, looking like this:
[image]

Sea shores which never dry out to the fine, crumbly state are not sandy beaches, they are mud flats which contain organic material.

If you got wet sand in your hair you could probably brush it out once it was dry. But if you got wet mud in your hair you would definitely have to wash it because it would dry to a solid state, caking your hair. It would also probably stink.

This is why we make pottery out of clay (a particular kind of semi-dry mud in pliable form) and not wet sand.

Answer (score 0):

At its most general, mud could really be said to be any mixture of particles and a liquid. Most typically it is fine (organic and mineral) particles of earth (dirt), plus water.

IOW, typically mud has fine, clay particles, not coarse, sand particles. But *mud* is a term that can be used in different ways. One common use of the term *mud* refers to wet cement or mortar.

So the answer is:

- No, generally sand + water is not called mud.
- Yes, sand + water could be called mud.

Comment: Except that mortar "mud" also contains fine cement particles, which is what gives mortar its sticky nature.

Comment: @HotLicks: How is that an exception to what I said?

Comment: Sand+water isn't "mud".  Sand+water+cement is "mud".

Comment: @HotLicks: For a mason, yes. For someone building a sand sculpture or someone stuck in quicksand, perhaps sand + water is mud - sticky, gooey, viscous mud. The concept is, well, fluid. It can even apply to non-Newtonian fluids: cornstarch + water is mud (IMHO).

Comment: @Drew Cornstarch + water is mud???? Can you give an example of this?

Comment: @Mynamite: I just did. ;-) Oh, and wet sand does not always dry out to "dry, crumbly particles." Sandstone is about as solid as cement. And sand, wet or dry, is not necessarily void of organic material and clay particles. These things are relative, and the concept of mud is about as fluid as is mud itself.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you would say that your hair was **covered** or (more poetically) **plastered** with wet sand and that it became **caked** with sand if left to dry.

This *could* be called a mud (but probably would not be). A lot of heavy, dirty gloop is called *mud*. For example there are *anode muds* in electroplating which is gunk which collects during the process. Along with its consistency and colour, generally there is the implication that a mud is somehow of low value, dirty, messy, or otherwise disdained (which is unlikely here).

Without qualification, however, mud in non-technical contexts involves soil. This further reduces the likelihood of application to wet sand.

**Muddy** has at least two related meanings. It can mean *mudded* (*ie* covered in mud), but it can also mean *like* mud (dark, thick and opaque). This latter meaning is just about possible in the context of wet sand.

In technical contexts florid analogies tend to get pickled into jargon, so it wouldn't surprise me to see it described as mud in, for example, a civil engineering textbook.

You might write an extended description of this mixture as follows:

> At low tide, the sea recedes to reveal a heavy, saturated sand which has the consistency of mud. Such sand readily coats most surfaces and, once dry, will cake them in fine sand.